# How to use ggplot2 to present bar graphs of counts where data stored in multiple columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset describing injury prevalence that I am trying to sumarise for initial analysis.

Injuries =

```
    ID    Injury.face    Injury.neck    Injury.chest    Injury.pelvis    Inj.loc.count
    1     Checked        Unchecked      Unchecked       Unchecked        1
    2     Unchecked      Checked        Unchecked       Checked          2
    3     Checked        Unchecked      Checked         Unchecked        2
    4     Unchecked      Checked        Checked         Checked          3
    5     Unchecked      Unchecked      Unchecked       Checked          1
```

I would like to display the data using ggplot2 so that I can see the frequency of injury by location in a bar chart and facet the bar chart by the column Inj.loc.count.

The dataset is a subset of a larger table and there are 10 injury.X columns.
Inj.loc.count is a count of the number of "checked" values across each row.

I am struggling with how to display a count of each injury.X column as a bar.

My searches prior to submitting this post have all yielded posts where the variables to be displayed in multiple bars are in one column.

Apologies if I make some errors in formatting this is my first SO post.

Comment: Would you include your R code in the question?

Comment: What specific R code were you referring to? The code to calculate inj.loc.count?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the reshape2 library to cast to the proper format before plotting.

```
reformatted <- melt(Injuries, id.vars = c("id")
```

Then feed that into ggplot. You'll have a variable column that you can facet over

Comment: Thank you very much. I made use of this process. This is the code I used:        #Reshape the Injury data table
reformatted <- melt(Injuries, id.vars = c("id", 'inj.loc.count'))
#replace Checked/unchecked with 1/0
reformatted <- reformatted %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == "Unchecked",0,1))
reformatted <- subset(reformatted, value == 1)
#Plot facet
ggplot(reformatted, aes(x = variable)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~inj.loc.count) +
  labs(x="", y="No. Patients with injury") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())

Answer (score 1):

**tidyr** approach would be:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Injury.face = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("Checked", "Unchecked"), class = "factor"), 
    Injury.neck = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Checked", 
    "Unchecked"), class = "factor"), Injury.chest = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Checked", "Unchecked"), class = "factor"), 
    Injury.pelvis = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Checked", 
    "Unchecked"), class = "factor"), Inj.loc.count = c(1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "Injury.face", "Injury.neck", 
    "Injury.chest", "Injury.pelvis", "Inj.loc.count"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -5L))

new <- gather(df, key=c(ID, Inj.loc.count), Injury, -ID, -Inj.loc.count)
colnames(new) <- c("ID", "Inj.loc.count", "Name", "Injury")

> head(new, 10)
   ID Inj.loc.count        Name    Injury
1   1             1 Injury.face   Checked
2   2             2 Injury.face Unchecked
3   3             2 Injury.face   Checked
4   4             3 Injury.face Unchecked
5   5             1 Injury.face Unchecked
6   1             1 Injury.neck Unchecked
7   2             2 Injury.neck   Checked
8   3             2 Injury.neck Unchecked
9   4             3 Injury.neck   Checked
10  5             1 Injury.neck Unchecked


# count checked/unchecked injuries
n <- new %>% group_by(Name, Injury) %>% count

# join n to main df by Name and Injury type
new_df <- new %>% left_join(n, by=c("Name", "Injury")) %>% mutate(Name = gsub("Injury.","", Name))

# plot the data, faceted by Inj.loc.count
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = Name, y = n, fill = Injury)) +
      geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
      facet_wrap(~Inj.loc.count, ncol = 1)+
      geom_text(aes(label=n), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                    vjust=1.5, color = "white", fontface = "bold") +
      labs(y = "Number of cases")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am not familiar with tidyr so I will revisit this answer again in the future. I ended up using reshape2 to transform the data into a more manageable format and I was then able to output a comparable output. I have used your bar label suggestion as that is a neat solution to add detail.

Comment: Bear in mind that tidyr or dplyr fun outperforms reshape2 functions.